# How to analyze analog output waveform in Modelsim

Tags: fpga, analog, vhdl, wave

I want to analyze an output sine signal from my VHDL code in Modelsim. I have created a project and simulated the code. However the outout in the "Wave" window is in binary form represented as a 32 bit output. I tried to change my signal as a Analog signal in wave properties but nothing really changed. I would like to se an analog output signal in decimal format which resemples a sine wave. How do I do this?

Comment: Modelsim can display analog waveforms, oscilloscope style, as well as digital signals. They might have to be integer or real, or numeric_std.signed or unsigned.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, my answer felt wrong when I typed it! Thanks and corrected below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. On the Wave window, select your signals and right-click Under 'Format', select 'Analog' to see your signal as an analogue wave.

If you have a lot of data, you could write VHDL to write your values data into an output file in .CSV format (Comma-Separated Values). Then you could import that .CSV file into Excel and plot a graph from it.